# Why does performing a cout on a number allocate memory to the heap?

Tags: c++, memory, heap-memory

Like the title says, when I perform a cout on any type of number(float, int, double, etc) it allocates 7 indices to the heap. Does anyone know what causes this behavior, or is it an issue with something else in my code.

Images showing the behavior:
Before cout is called
[image]

After it's called
[image]

Comment: cout is an object. It could be initialized lazily at first use.

Comment: Probably because your system does not support printing numbers, only text, so `std::cout` has to convert your number to text in a text buffer which uses memory.

Comment: Please don't link to external resources in your question and please post relevant info as *text* *in* the question, not as images - if at all possible.

Comment: On what operating system and with what standard C++ and C libraries and what C++ compiler ?

Comment: The images are so small that they are unreadable so your question is unclear. Your C++ source code should appear as text (with four spaces at start of every line) in the question, not as an image

Answer (score -1):

The C++ standard library can use dynamic memory allocation for internal purposes (notably buffering). Quite probably your standard C++ [input/output library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io) is using dynamic memory (which is extremely common).

<sup>(BTW, the C++ standard does not specify that your implementation runs on a computer; you might use a bunch of human slaves instead but that is not ethical)</sup>

I guess that `std::cout` has some buffer lazily allocated on your particular implementation (this is operating system- , C & C++ standard libraries- , and C++ compiler-  specific).

Your C++ implementation is right in allocating that lazily, because the C++ mantra is to don't pay for something you don't use. So an hypothetical C++ program not using any standard C++ I/O won't consume these bytes on your platform.

To really understand what is precisely happening, you need to dive into your C++ implementation (internals). Using a [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software) C++ compiler, a free software standard C and C++ libraries, a free software operating system is helpful to understand these details (so I recommend using some Linux distribution) by diving into appropriate source code. Otherwise, spend months or years of efforts on reverse-engineering your C++ implementation (which BTW might perhaps be illegal in some countries).

But you should not care (and it looks that you are sadly using some proprietary C++ implementation, whose source code you are probably forbidden to study, without signing some costly NDA).

Perhaps flushing or closing your `std::cout` might release some memory (but again, this is implementation specific).

In practice most C++ programs depend on *many* resources (which indirectly consumes memory, etc...). A notable exception is the embedded world, where you might code in some freestanding subset of C++ and choose carefully the parts of C++ that you need to use (even indirectly).

<sup>(apparently some parts of the C++ standard library is available in source form on Windows; but I never used Windows)</sup>

Comment: It's slightly a shame that you'd use this platform to preach FOSS. But that's none of my business.

Comment: What's wrong with saying "it's easier to look under the hood of a FOSS C++ implementation than a proprietary one?" That's objectively true.

Comment: @cdhowie He's doing more than that. You only need the see the source code. But there's an overemphasis on the "free" aspect which is, quite frankly, irrelevant to the answer.

Comment: I mentioning the costly NDA possibility. But I don't think that the average C++ newbie can legally access to all the source code related to C++ on Windows without paying a lot of money.

Comment: @Mysticial "free" is mentioned only as qualifiers for "C++ compiler", "...libraries", and "operating system", in the context of "To really understand what is precisely happening, you need to dive into your C++ implementation (internals)"  If you assume "free" is shorthand for "free open-source software", that's merely stating the fact that such software eases thoroughly analyzing an entire implementation.  I don't read it as evangelizing "free" software at all.

Comment: I definitely read it as doing such. The neutral term would be "open source". GPL is not any more actually free than MSVC. In fact I would suggest considerably less free.

Comment: The only source code that has any possible relevance to the question is that used by `std::cout`. One need not sign any expensive NDAs (or much of anything else) to look at the soruce code for the MS VC++ standard library. The discussion (and recommendation) of open source software is a *complete* red herring.